# Linking to endpoints from the client-side in WebSharper

Tags: f#, websharper

In sitelets it's rather easy to create links to other endpoints with parameters. For example `ctx.Link(EndPoint.ShowUser user.id))` creates a link to the ShowUser endpoint with a specific ID.

Now I'm migrating some code to the client side to dynamically update a table once a new item is created; the table has action links that point to other endpoints. Is there something like `ctx.Link` on the client side I can use?

I'd rather avoid creating the link by myself (e.g. with sprintf) because I want the EndPoint type to be authorative for everything URL related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Router<EndPoint>` value on the client side and use it to create links:

```
open WebSharper.Sitelets.InferRouter

let router = Router.Infer<EndPoint>()

let link = router.Link(EndPoint.ShowUser user.id)
```